# How tweens matrices between keyframes CSS are made?

Tags: css, svg, svg-animate

How can you change the way make use key frames when transform-matrix to perform, in a circular interpolation matrix?

The movement made from one key frame to another does not guara the center even if they are closely spaced key frames

```html
<svg version="1.1" id="Capa_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" width="100%" height="800" viewBox="0 0 100% 800" enable-background="new 0 0 100% 800" xml:space="preserve">
  <g id="todo">
    <defs>
      <style type="text/css">
        .a1621 {
          animation-duration: 35s;
          animation-iteration-count: 1;
          animation-direction: normal;
          animation-play-state: running;
          animation-name: a1621;
          transform-origin: 0px 0px 0px;
        }
        @keyframes a1621 {
          0% {
            transform: matrix3d(1.94872, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.94872, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.94872, 0, -354.819, -265.641, 0, 1);
          }
          100% {
            transform: matrix3d(1.17277, 1.55632, 0, 0, -1.55632, 1.17277, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.94872, 0, 371.155, -630.437, 0, 1);
          }
        }
      </style>
    </defs>

    <g id="1621">
      <g fill="" stroke="" stroke-width="" name="draga" id="Rectangulo1621" class="a1621" style="transform: matrix3d(1.9487160000000001,0,0,0,0,1.9487160000000001,0,0,0,0,1.9487160000000001,0,-354.819344,-265.64068,0,1)">
        <g>
          <rect stroke="none" stroke-width="" x="324" y="250" width="100" height="60"></rect>
        </g>
      </g>
    </g>
    <g id="1622">
      <g fill="" stroke="" stroke-width="" name="draga" id="Rectangulo1622" class="a1622" style="transform: matrix3d(1.1727689719168597,1.5563169911393604,0,0,-1.5563169911393604,1.1727689719168597,0,0,0,0,1.94872,0,371.1554420221154,-630.4372668228414,0,1)">
        <g>
          <rect fill="rgb(4, 180, 95)" stroke="none" stroke-width="" x="324" y="250" width="100" height="60"></rect>
        </g>
      </g>
    </g>
  </g>
</svg>
```

http://codepen.io/mateos1/pen/mEVomZ
[foo](http://codepen.io/mateos1/pen/mEVomZ)

Comment: You might be looking for https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation-fill-mode : http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/wWMZBJ not too sure of result expected actually.

Comment: and probe with different types of syntax properties and none makes me a pure rotation movements in the matrix intepolacion thanks and greetings from Spain

Comment: okay, is this what you look for : http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/MeKROz or http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/yJerpR ?

Comment: indeed what the aim is to make a simple rotate 55 deg but with matrices, start and end are correct, but the move should not move to the center more examples of creating transformations svg www.animacionesweb.es

Comment: If you want simple rotation, why do you use complex 3d transformation instead of simple rotation (or simple matrix)? I guess you have problem with SVG, because of transform-origin in SVG is set to 0, 0 (instead of center of block in HTML). See https://css-tricks.com/transforms-on-svg-elements/

Comment: in a single array can be collected translation, rotation and scale of a svg so much more to create complex animations       http://codepen.io/mateos1/pen/rLexdR                  [link](http://codepen.io/mateos1/pen/rLexdR)